# Can I have local push notifications which triggers or function in my app?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I want to use Local Push Notifications for iOS and Android based on the logic of the app. Basically I want to have a silent background notification every X ours which then triggers a function in my app which decides if the real notification will be displayed.

Can this be achieved with local push notification or do I need remote push notification?

**[EDIT]**
Apparently my question is not clear enough so I add this example:

In my app I have a function which returns a string depending on some logic. I will start a local push notification every X hours which then calls this function to determine which string will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [react-native-background-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task) to start a background service that you can schedule to be called every x hours.

Comment: So I could use a background task which then fires a local push notification. I hope there is a better way, but this could work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React Native Push Notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) , use Scheduled Notifications ..

The have a example code like below

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    autoCancel: true,
    bigText:
      'This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.',
    subText: 'Local Notification Demo',
    title: 'Scheduled Notification Title',
    message: 'Scheduled Notification Message',
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 500,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: 'default',
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]',
    date: new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 1000) // in 3 secs
  })
```

Comment: Yes, but I need a callback from my app which contains some logic. I will edit my question to make this more clear.